# Mybook 6tb drive making noises

Tags: external-hard-drive, mybook

i purchased a [Mybook 6tb](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KU686HI) drive from Amazon about a year ago.

For about the past month or two its been making noises i have two of the drives and they both seem to be making the same noise, they both made noise right out of the box but over the last couple of months it has become much more apparent.

Here are the noises its been making.

http://vocaroo.com/i/s0vNJRJtTxq4

Is this normal Mybook behavior or is something wrong?

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

That is not good.

Having worked at the US post office, I can tell you that all small parcels are thrown by mail clerks from a center staging area into the container for the route's mail carrier, normally a distance of 15 to 25 feet.  Every small parcel is handled like this.

I have also sold hard drives on eBay and stopped doing so, because more than half of them had similar failures after delivery and were returned.

I've decided to only buy locally where inventory is shipped in bulk, and not individually.

Sorry you're frustrated.  I get it.

Comment: Damn, Well thanks man.
Guess im going to have to go and replace the hard drives now.

do you think it'll be fine to transfer everything off of the drive?
there's over 5tb on the drive.

Comment: Hopefully, whatever the issue, you can use your drive normally and back up your data.  I would consider the drive unreliable and make use of it accordingly.  I use an array of disks I consider unreliable in a datastore that's backed up nightly.  Nothing in that store is irreplaceable (media library, for example), yet I want ready access to it and if it breaks, it gets replaced and restored.